# Running node.js libraries on iOS

Tags: ios, node.js, swift

I have a need of using node.js libraries on iPad/iPhone, like tone.js to trigger generate sounds, see https://tonejs.github.io/

The app itself can be a react native app or based on Swift.

Are there any modern possibilities, or maybe there are better ways of doing than doing it with node?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the web audio api used by tonejs works outside of a webview.
for react native use

https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound